# Determining the tag of a cache

Tags: caching

Given a cache with 256 blocks, and 16 bytes per block, how can I determine the value of the tag field of a cache block that holds the 24-bit address 0x3CFBCF? Would there be any differences depending on whether the cache was direct-mapped, fully associative, or n-way set-asscociative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/arch/cache-addressing.xhtml) gives a great overview on finding the SET, TAG, and OFFSET of an address.